# relative clause having two gaps

Tags: relative-clauses

[This movie clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTeiNqBdTr0) starts with a teacher saying this line:

> (1) *Okay, now that we've finished our tests, I want you all to start thinking about our fifth grade science fair projects, **which you will need to work on to have ready after spring break**.*

Where the relative clause is shown in bold and its antecedent is *our fifth grade science fair projects*.

Now, can you insert a pronoun (*them*) that refers back to *our fifth grade science fair projects* after either ***work on*** or ***have*** as follows?

> (2) *Okay, now that we've finished our tests, I want you all to start thinking about our fifth grade science fair projects, **which you will need to work on them to have ready after spring break**.*
>
> (3) *Okay, now that we've finished our tests, I want you all to start thinking about our fifth grade science fair projects, **which you will need to work on to have them ready after spring break**.*

Is (2) or (3) or both natural English or even grammatical?

If grammatical and natural, how natural are they compared to (1)?

Comment: *Today we're going to study calculus, which you'll need to know to pass your exams.* Nothing unusual about that phrasing (or your teacher's original). Your rephrasing #2 is grammatically invalid in modern English (but would have been acceptable to some Victorian dialect speakers). And whilst explicitly identifying the object ***them*** in  #3 is okay, it's not *required*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your example has only one gap. How about this? _Today we're going to study calculus, which you'll need to know to pass your exams on._ vs. _Today we're going to study calculus, which you'll need to know to pass your exams on it._

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, (3) is less natural than (1)?

Comment: As implied by the last sentence of my first comment, #3 is neither more nor less "natural" than "re-identifying" the object. In your case the object is *our fifth grade science fair projects* - which you've already referred back to with ***which*** (but doing it again with ***them*** is perfectly okay too). The difference between including ***it*** in your comment example is that this implies the exams are *primarily* testing calculus skills, whereas without it those skills might be a relatively minor aspect (but still necessary in order to pass).

Comment: ...but I have to say that it's not really worth you thinking about the merits of #1 as opposed to #3 (trivial details, imho) unless and until you have a clear understanding of why your suggested #2 is completely unacceptable. In which context you might want to have a look at [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/335605/why-answer-with-which-it-is) about unusual / outdated use of ***which***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the link to that ELU question about "outdated" use of _which_. But I still think my #2 is clearly different from those "outdated" uses in that #2 has a gap between _have_ and _ready_ whereas the latter doesn't have any gap.